# Cycles or Multiple Cascade Paths Many to Many Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have classes Sale, Product and Occasions.  A sales must refer to a single product and the product may have several Occasions.  A customer may want to buy only certain occasions of the product.   After I created a one to many between product and purchase, I also want to create a many to many relationship between Sales and Occasions to track which occasions are included in a Sales item.  Here are the classes

```
public class Sale
{      
    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public Sale()
    {
        Occasions = new List<Occasion>(); 
    }
    public virtual ICollection<Occasion> Occasions { get; set; }
}
 public class Occasion
{           
    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Sale> Sales{ get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
    public virtual ICollection<Occasion> Occasions { get; set; }
}
```

Creating the many to many relationship by the following code

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Sale>().
            HasMany(p => p.Occasions).
            WithMany(o => o.Sale).
            Map(
            m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("SaleId");
                m.MapRightKey("OccasionId");
                m.ToTable("SaleOccasions");
            });
    }
```

and updating the databse would return error

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.SaleeOccasions_dbo.Occasions_OccasionId' on table 'SaleeOccasions' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths . . .

If I delete `cascadeDelete: true` from the migration, I am able to create the join-table and create new entries but when I try to delete a sale after removing the reference to occasions (`sale.Occasions.Remove(occasion)` for all occasions related with a sale) would throw

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint..

I thought of a work-around by discarding the EF relationship between Sale and Occasions altogether and instead to create a String property in Sale that changes the list of Occasion id's to a single string, but I feel that is not a good solution.  Any better solutions?